# In java, is there any way to connect to other host by TCP/IP without "while(true)"

Tags: java, sockets, io

everybody. There was a problem, I was thinking for a long time.
I can conntect other host by "socket". I used "socketServer.accept()". When there was someone calling me, I can know. Here is the code.

```
while (this.connState != 0) {
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And then I can get the 'stream', and get my data.

But I don't want to get it by that way.

I want to tell the OS that what I will do when I get my data. If it is possible, I don't have to check the socket every time. Can I do that? Is there any interface or event I can use?

Comment: Your code sample is an infinite loop. What line of code would ever set `this.connState` to something other than zero?

Comment: I think what you are really trying to say is, "how can I avoid the blocking nature of socket.accept?"

Comment: no, that is not at all a duplicate of that question .... not even remotely

Comment: Can [Akka](http://akka.io/) do this?

Comment: thats highly doubtful ... unless it has a mapping to asynchronous NIO or something similar.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what OP is asking.... Please clarify what your exact question is using proper grammar

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `while()` loop; in that case, the server will simply accept a single connection and terminate.

This isn't a "busy loop." `ServerSocket.accept()` will block until a connection is being made.

As explained in another answer, you can use NIO. Another option is Akka as explained in "[Using TCP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/io-tcp.html)" (no, I'm not copy&pasting ~200 lines of code from the Akka docs here).

While the setup of Akka looks insanely expensive, the rewards is a powerful system to slice&dice your incoming connections turn them into messages, route them through actors which either return results or pass the message on to other actors.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Java NIO supports this : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html

Heres a useful example which doesnt use (error-prone) loops : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0080__Java_Network_Asynchronous_Socket_Channels.htm

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
        .open();/*  ww w . j av a 2s. c om*/
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 8989;
    InetSocketAddress sAddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    server.bind(sAddr);
    System.out.format("Server is listening at %s%n", sAddr);
    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.server = server;
    server.accept(attach, new ConnectionHandler());
    Thread.currentThread().join();
  }
}
class Attachment {
  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel server;
  AsynchronousSocketChannel client;
  ByteBuffer buffer;
  SocketAddress clientAddr;
  boolean isRead;
}

class ConnectionHandler implements
    CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel client, Attachment attach) {
    try {
      SocketAddress clientAddr = client.getRemoteAddress();
      System.out.format("Accepted a  connection from  %s%n", clientAddr);
      attach.server.accept(attach, this);
      ReadWriteHandler rwHandler = new ReadWriteHandler();
      Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
      newAttach.server = attach.server;
      newAttach.client = client;
      newAttach.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
      newAttach.isRead = true;
      newAttach.clientAddr = clientAddr;
      client.read(newAttach.buffer, newAttach, rwHandler);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    System.out.println("Failed to accept a  connection.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

class ReadWriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Attachment> {
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, Attachment attach) {
    if (result == -1) {
      try {
        attach.client.close();
        System.out.format("Stopped   listening to the   client %s%n",
            attach.clientAddr);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return;
    }

    if (attach.isRead) {
      attach.buffer.flip();
      int limits = attach.buffer.limit();
      byte bytes[] = new byte[limits];
      attach.buffer.get(bytes, 0, limits);
      Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
      String msg = new String(bytes, cs);
      System.out.format("Client at  %s  says: %s%n", attach.clientAddr,
          msg);
      attach.isRead = false; // It is a write
      attach.buffer.rewind();

    } else {
      // Write to the client
      attach.client.write(attach.buffer, attach, this);
      attach.isRead = true;
      attach.buffer.clear();
      attach.client.read(attach.buffer, attach, this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable e, Attachment attach) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

You can prevent the main-thread from exiting with `AsynchronousChannelGroup` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448743/351861

Comment: That seems what I want. Thank you.

Comment: very good - in that case please "accept" the answer so that the board can categorize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I wonder if you are talking about a reactive programming approach.

With a tool like [Akka,](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/intro/what-is-akka.html) you can write a handler that the system calls when data is received. It handles a lot of the low level details like threading and sockets. You just write [the code that says what to do](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/io-tcp.html#accepting-connections) when data is received.

Akka's networking capabilities are highly scalable, built on Java's "new" I/O (NIO) libraries, which can be used in a non-blocking, selector-based mode. (Akka uses [Netty,](http://netty.io/) which is built on these lower level NIO packages, for its remote message dispatch capability; I think Akka's networking packages might use Netty too.)